# Validate only parts of a form

Tags: forms, validation, xpages

I have a rather large form, that I've broken up into individual sections with "Next" and "Back" buttons for the user to navigate each step.

Here is how I set it up to work for now:

- Each section is within its own xp:panel
- Each xp:panel is hidden with "display:none". The transition happens when the user clicks on "Next" or "Back" by using JQuery's fade animation

What I am trying to do is, if the user clicks on "Next" I would like to validate only the fields in the current, visible section. If the validation fails, don't transition to the next step. If the validation passes, transition to the next step.

Right now, when I click on the "Next" button, every field is being validated and the transition doesn't happen.

Is there a way, that I can only validate the fields in a certain section or would I have to use something like Don Mottolo's code snippet: http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=ssjs-form-validation-that-triggers-errormessage-controls

Thank you for your help!

P.S.: I know I could use the CSJS portion of the onClick event of the button to run some validation, but I'd like to use the "Display Error" controls.

Comment: which language, c#, java?

Comment: Hello Piyush, thank you for your comment. This is XPages development and we mostly use JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at computing the `required` attribute of each control that is to be validated and have that check which button is submitting the form.  Tommy Vaaland has a function that does this:

```
// Used to check which if a component triggered an update
function submittedBy( componentId ){
 try {
  var eventHandlerClientId = param.get( '$$xspsubmitid' );
  var eventHandlerId = @RightBack( eventHandlerClientId, ':' );
  var eventHandler = getComponent( eventHandlerId );  
  if( !eventHandler ){ return false; }

  var parentComponent = eventHandler.getParent();
  if( !parentComponent ){ return false; }

  return ( parentComponent.getId() === componentId );  
 } catch( e ){ /*Debug.logException( e );*/ }
}
```

Link: http://dontpanic82.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/xpages-making-validation-behave.html

Comment: Hello Rob, thank you for your response. The seems to be the way to go. I'll try that and let everyone know

Comment: Hello Rob, this does work very well. You can actually implement that check for the property "disableValidators" (can be found in the "All Properties" tab under the section "data") of a field. That way, if your field has more than one validator and / or more complex validators, you don't have to add it to each and every one.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel F.  As I often find with answering a question on here, I find out more about technology with every answer I provide :-)

Comment: that is true. I just wish, the documentation for XPages was more informative and comprehensive. When I look over all the properties of the individual controls, I wonder sometimes, what they could be used for and how it would help me to improve my users' experience using the applications I develop.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at using a client side form validation framework such as Parsley: http://parsleyjs.org

This can of course be combined with server side validation for at least the final submission.

Comment: Hello Per, thank you for your response. Do you have any experience using it in combination with Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, I am using Parsley on a project that uses Bootstrap.